# How to reduce volume of wav stream?

Tags: audio, wav, flac

I have a flac file. I want to decode it through the "flac -dc" command, read the wav stream that the command outputs, decrease the volume by half and output the signal back. Here is my actual code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {

   FILE *stream;
   int16_t normal, decreased;

   stream = popen( "/usr/bin/flac -dc 1.flac", "r" );

   while( feof( stream ) == 0 ) {

       normal = fgetc( stream );
       decreased = (int16_t) (normal * 0.5f);

       printf( "%c", decreased );
   }

   pclose( stream );

   return 0;
}
```

But when I run this program and redirect its output to the audio system by this command:

```
./myprogram | aplay -f dc
```

the sound is highly distorted. The situation doesn't change if I try to decode a mp3 file trough the "mpg123 -s" command. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that flac is decoding to a bit depth higher than 8-bits. In which case you'd need to assemble two bytes into a short and then multiply by the gain.  Imagine an 16-bit sample of 0x7fff. When dividing by two you'd expect the result to be 0x3fff. But since you are dividing each byte separately you're result is going to be 0x3f7f.  Another issue you need to watch out for is the sign.

Untested but something like this should work for 16 bit signed:

```
while( feof( stream ) == 0 ) {
    normal = (int16_t)((fgetc(stream) << 8) | (fgetc(stream));
    decreased = (int16_t) (normal * 0.5f);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I have resolved in another way. The problem was that the "fgetc" function returns an unsigned int even if the wav stream is actually signed, so for example (ignoring the two's complement) if I halfed the unsigned char 178, that is -50 in signed char, i got 89 and not -25 as expected. The solutions at this point were two: or making aplay accept unsigned 8bit data or forcing the fgetc return value in a signed variable. I chose the second path. Now it works smoothly. Thanks however for help.

Comment: @giuliom_95. You should make certain the data is 8-bit signed and not 16-bit signed. It would be unusual to have 8-bit data come out of either flac or mp3.