# Decreasing volume of .wav file creates heavy distortion

Tags: c#, audio, wav

I have a problem that just baffles me. I import a .wav file and read them as bytes. Then I turn them into integers that I then all divide by 2 (or some other number) in order to decrease the volume. Then I make a new .wav file into which I put the new data. The result is loud and heavy distortion over the original track.

Scroll to the Main() method for the relevant (C#-)code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp2 {
    class basic {
        public static byte[] bit32(int num) { //turns int into byte array of length 4
            byte[] numbyt = new byte[4] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
            int pow;
            for (int k = 3; k >= 0; k--) {
                pow = (int)Math.Pow(16, 2*k + 1);
                numbyt[k] += (byte)(16*(num/pow));
                num -= numbyt[k]*(pow/16);
                numbyt[k] += (byte)(num/(pow/16));
                num -= (num/(pow/16))*pow/16;
            }
            return numbyt;
        }
        public static byte[] bit16(int num) { //turns int into byte array of length 2
            if (num < 0) {
                num += 65535;
            }
            byte[] numbyt = new byte[2] { 0x00, 0x00 };
            int pow;
            for (int k = 1; k >= 0; k--) {
                pow = (int)Math.Pow(16, 2*k + 1);
                numbyt[k] += (byte)(16*(num/pow));
                num -= numbyt[k]*(pow/16);
                numbyt[k] += (byte)(num/(pow/16));
                num -= (num/(pow/16))*pow/16;
            }
            return numbyt;
        }
        public static int bitint16(byte[] numbyt) { //turns byte array of length 2 into int
            int num = 0;
            num += (int)Math.Pow(16, 2)*numbyt[1];
            num += numbyt[0];
            return num;
        }
    }
    class wavfile: FileStream {
        public wavfile(string name, int len) : base(name, FileMode.Create) {
            int samplerate = 44100;
            byte[] riff = new byte[] { 0x52, 0x49, 0x46, 0x46 };
            this.Write(riff, 0, 4);
            byte[] chunksize;
            chunksize = basic.bit32(36 + len*4);
            this.Write(chunksize, 0, 4);
            byte[] wavebyte = new byte[4] { 0x57, 0x41, 0x56, 0x45 };
            this.Write(wavebyte, 0, 4);
            byte[] fmt = new byte[] { 0x66, 0x6d, 0x74, 0x20 };
            this.Write(fmt, 0, 4);
            byte[] subchunk1size = new byte[] { 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
            this.Write(subchunk1size, 0, 4);
            byte[] formchann = new byte[] { 0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00 };
            this.Write(formchann, 0, 4);
            byte[] sampleratebyte = basic.bit32(samplerate);
            this.Write(sampleratebyte, 0, 4);
            byte[] byterate = basic.bit32(samplerate*4);
            this.Write(byterate, 0, 4);
            byte[] blockalign = new byte[] { 0x04, 0x00 };
            this.Write(blockalign, 0, 2);
            byte[] bits = new byte[] { 0x10, 0x00 };
            this.Write(bits, 0, 2);
            byte[] data = new byte[] { 0x64, 0x61, 0x74, 0x61 };
            this.Write(data, 0, 4);
            byte[] samplesbyte = basic.bit32(len*4);
            this.Write(samplesbyte, 0, 4);
        }
        public void sound(int[] w, int len, wavfile wavorigin = null) {
            byte[] wavbyt = new byte[len*4];
            for (int t = 0; t < len*2; t++) {
                byte[] wavbit16 = basic.bit16(w[t]);
                wavbyt[2*t] = wavbit16[0];
                wavbyt[2*t + 1] = wavbit16[1];
            }
            this.Write(wavbyt, 0, len*4);
            System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
            player.SoundLocation = this.Name;
            while (true) {
                player.Play();
                Console.WriteLine("repeat?");
                if (Console.ReadLine() == "no") {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    class Program {
        static void Main() {
            int[] song = new int[45000*2];
            byte[] songbyt = File.ReadAllBytes("name.wav"); //use your stereo, 16bits per sample wav-file
            for (int t = 0; t < 45000*2; t++) {
                byte[] songbytsamp = new byte[2] { songbyt[44 + 2*t], songbyt[44 + 2*t + 1] }; //I skip the header
                song[t] = basic.bitint16(songbytsamp)/2; //I divide by 2 here, remove the "/2" to hear the normal sound again
                //song[t] *= 2;
            }
            wavfile wav = new wavfile("test.wav", 45000); //constructor class that writes the header of a .wav file
            wav.sound(song, 45000); //method that writes the data from "song" into the .wav file
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is not the rounding down that happens when you divide an odd number by 2; you can uncomment the line that says `song[t] *= 2;` and hear for yourself that all of the distortion has completely disappeared again.

I must be making a small stupid mistake somewhere, but I cannot find it. I just want to make the sound data quieter to avoid distortion when I add more sounds to it.

Comment: What's all that Math.Pow code do? You have comments that indicate indicate you are doing some bit and byte twizzling. What's Math.Pow doing there

Comment: We could go into that, but you can copy my code and see that it works (if you remove the "/2" of course), so I'm pretty sure the problem doesn't lie there. Anyway, I check how many multiples of 16^(2k+1) are inside the integer by dividing, then multiply it by 16 to add it to the k-th element of the byte array (little endian), and then substract 16^(2k+1) from the integer. Then I check 16^k, and divide the integer in question again by it, multiply it by 1, and add it to the k-th element and substract again. Then it goes to the (k-1)-th iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I knew it would be something stupid, and I was right. I forgot to account for the fact that negative numbers are written in signed 16 bit language as the numbers above 2^15, and when you divide by 2, you push them into (very large) positive values. I altered my code to substract 2^16 from any number that's above 2^15 before dividing by 2. I have to thank this person though: [How to reduce volume of wav stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33368350/how-to-reduce-volume-of-wav-stream?rq=1)
If this means that my question was a duplicate, then go ahead and delete it, but I'm letting it stay for now, because someone else might find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Math.Pow` to do bit and byte operations is a really bad idea. That function takes `double` values as inputs and returns a double.  It also does exponentiation (not a trivial operation).  Using traditional bit shift and mask operations is clearer, *much* faster and less likely to introduce noise (because of the inaccuracy of doubles).

As you noticed, you *really* want to work with *unsigned* quantities (like *uint/UInt32* and *ushort/UInt16*).  Sign extension trips up everyone when doing this sort of work.

This is not a full answer to your question, but it does present a way to do the byte operations that is arguably better.

First, create a small struct to hold a combination of a bit-mask and a shift quantity:

```
public struct MaskAndShift {
    public uint Mask {get; set;}
    public int Shift {get; set;}
}
```

Then I create two arrays of these structs for describing what should be done to extract individual bytes from a `uint` or a `ushort`.  I put them both in a static class named `Worker`:

```
public static class Worker {
    public static MaskAndShift[] Mask32 = new  MaskAndShift[] {
        new MaskAndShift {Mask = 0xFF000000, Shift = 24},
        new MaskAndShift {Mask = 0x00FF0000, Shift = 16},
        new MaskAndShift {Mask = 0x0000FF00, Shift = 8},
        new MaskAndShift {Mask = 0x000000FF, Shift = 0},
    };
    public static  MaskAndShift[] Mask16 = new  MaskAndShift[] {
        new MaskAndShift {Mask = 0x0000FF00, Shift = 8},
        new MaskAndShift {Mask = 0x000000FF, Shift = 0},
    };
}
```

Looking at the first entry in the first array, it says "to extract the first byte from a uint, mask that uint with `0xFF000000` and shift the result `24` bits to the right".  If you have endian-ness issues, you can simply re-order the entries in the array.

Then I created this static function (in the `Worker` class) to convert a `uint` / `UInt32` to an array of four bytes:

```
public static byte[] UintToByteArray (uint input) {
    var bytes = new byte[4];
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var maskPair in Mask32) {
        var masked = input & maskPair.Mask;
        if (maskPair.Shift != 0) {
            masked >>= maskPair.Shift;
        }
        bytes[i++] = (byte) masked;
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

The code to do the same operation for a 16 bit `ushort` (aka `UInt16`) looks nearly the same (there's probably an opportunity for some refactoring here):

```
public static byte[] UShortToByteArray (ushort input) {
    var bytes = new byte[2];
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var maskPair in Mask16) {
        var masked = input & maskPair.Mask;
        if (maskPair.Shift != 0) {
            masked >>= maskPair.Shift;
        }
        bytes[i++] = (byte) masked;
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

The reverse operation is much simpler (however, if you have endian-ness issues, you'll need to write the code).  Here I just take the entries of the array, add them into a value and shift the result:

```
public static uint ByteArrayToUint (byte[] bytes) {
    uint result = 0;
    //note that the first time through, result is zero, so shifting is a noop
    foreach (var b in bytes){
        result <<= 8;
        result += b;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Doing this for the 16 bit version ends up being effectively the same code, so...

```
public static ushort ByteArrayToUshort (byte[] bytes) {
    return (ushort) ByteArrayToUint(bytes); 
}
```

Bit-twiddling never works the first time.  So I wrote some test code:

```
public static void Main(){
    //pick a nice obvious pattern
    uint bit32Test = (((0xF1u * 0x100u) + 0xE2u) * 0x100u + 0xD3u) * 0x100u + 0xC4u;
    Console.WriteLine("Start");
    Console.WriteLine("Input 32 Value: " + bit32Test.ToString("X"));
    
    var bytes32 = Worker.UintToByteArray(bit32Test);
    foreach (var b in bytes32){
        Console.WriteLine(b.ToString("X"));
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    
    ushort bit16Test = (ushort)((0xB5u * 0x100u) + 0xA6u);
    Console.WriteLine("Input 16 Value: " + bit16Test.ToString("X"));
    
    var bytes16 = Worker.UShortToByteArray(bit16Test);
    foreach (var b in bytes16){
        Console.WriteLine(b.ToString("X"));
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\r\nNow the reverse");
    
    uint reconstitued32 = Worker.ByteArrayToUint(bytes32);
    Console.WriteLine("Reconstituted 32: " + reconstitued32.ToString("X"));
    
    ushort reconstitued16 = Worker.ByteArrayToUshort(bytes16);
    Console.WriteLine("Reconstituted 16: " + reconstitued16.ToString("X")); 
}
```

The output from that test code looks like:

```
Start
Input 32 Value: F1E2D3C4
F1
E2
D3
C4

Input 16 Value: B5A6
B5
A6

Now the reverse
Reconstituted 32: F1E2D3C4
Reconstituted 16: B5A6
```

Also note that I do everything in hexadecimal - it makes everything so much easier to read and to understand.

Comment: Well, it works fine. I find it hard to believe Math.Pow could cause errors when I'm only calculating the powers of 16; I could also just explicitly write them into an array and use that. In a lot of your code I'm not really understanding what you're doing, and I don't think it will affect the speed that much, but thanks anyways. About the unsigned integers: I'm writing the sound data in 16 bit, so there is enough space on an int for that; the 4 byte conversion I only use for the header (which are all positive values).

Comment: A `uint` (also known as a `UInt32`) is a 32-bit unsigned integer. A `ushort` (or a `UInt16`) is a 16-bit unsigned number. You should read up on the _binary and_ operator (`&`) and the _bit-shift_ operators like `>>`. Thevare really essential programmer tools. By the way, I wouldn't be surprised that my unsigned to byte array code runs 10x (or more) the speed of yours